What is the "fundamental" way of expressing division of polynomials
I am confused regarding the polynomial remainder theorem. When we want to find the remainder of a polynomial $f(x)$ on dividing it by the divisor $d(x)$ . Where $d(x)=x-a$ then we use the equation
$$f(x) = d(x) \cdot q(x) + r(x)$$
and we put x=a and evaluate the value of polynomial at x=a to find constant Remainder "R".
But doesn't that mean, that we are dividing the polynomial by "0"? Because let's just say instead of using this equation we use this equation
$\frac{f(x)}{d(x)} = q(x) + \frac{r(x)}{d(x)}$
Here we cannot make $d(x)$ "0". So I am confused as to which of these two equations is considered to be more "fundamental" and Why? I came across the same question on this platform a while ago but there was only one answer there which I think was just restating the same thing. I think we have to establish as to what we accept as more fundamental way to express division.

The equation ()=()⋅()+() should be right for every x also  including x=a. The equation is true, even if you do not know q(x) so you have not to divide to find R. That you can divide f(x) through x-a  and find q(x) and R has nothing to do with it.
